# how to use blowfish algorithm in different platforms?

Tags: encryption

I am trying to encrypt data in Android Studio (Java) and send that encrypted data using TCP communication to LabVIEW where it needs to be decrypted. Both Android and LabVIEW have predefined functions for encrypting and decrypting data using the blowfish algorithm but the Formats don't match and thus i am not able to decrypt the data at LabVIEW.I am new to this field and would really appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you show a small example?

Comment: There is no single answer for this. There is no standard format for encrypted data. You will need to implement the same format on both sides. I build custom formats like these for people on a consulting basis, but they're not particularly good StackOverflow questions because each solution is custom code that is basically unusable by anyone else. If you have LabVIEW source code, I'd be happy to discuss building a Java implementation if you have trouble getting an answer.

Comment: @EvilTeach i just tried with a simple TCP Server at LabVIEW which reads the data sent from the Client, which in my case is a Android phone. At the Android phone the user is asked to enter a string like Name,which is encrypted and then written to the Server. I have given the same string as key at both the platforms.

Comment: @RobNapier I am using the predefined classes and Methods like the SecretKey and Cipher class. Portion of my code: SecretKey skey = new SecretKeySpec(keyText.getBytes(),"Blowfish");      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish"); Do you mean that i need to do the encryption from Scratch?

Comment: Not the Blowfish portion. But you'll need to know how the key is generated (it's not clear in your example whether you have a proper key; it looks like you're doing it insecurely). You'll need to know how the IV is passed. You'll need to know if there is any metadata, and you'll need to deal with generating and validating the HMAC if there is one. There's a lot more to an encryption format than the core block cipher algorithm. Most of that would hopefully be visible in the LabVIEW source code or documentation.